# Can Db2 LAG function refer to itself?

Tags: sql, db2, lag

I'm trying to put information to identify GROUP ID by replicating this Excel formula:

```
IF(OR(A2<>A1,AND(B2<>"000",B1="000")),D1+1,D1)
```

This formula is written when my cursor is in "D2", meaning I've referred to the newly added column value in the previous row to generate the current value.

I'd like to this with Db2 SQL, but I'm not sure how to because I'll need to do LAG function on the column I'm going to add and referring their value.

[image]

Kindly advise if having better way to do.

Thanks.

Comment: The sorting is on the EVENT_TIMESTAMP? It should be possible to turn this into SQL. I have some examples with LAG and sorting in this blog post in which I have COVID-19 timeseries data as use case: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/learning-sql-a-look-behind-covid-19-numbers

Comment: Maybe you can use `LAG(column, 2)` instead.

Comment: I don't see why you want to use `LAG`, it seems what you want is `DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY  SERIAL_NUMBER, OPERATION)`

Comment: How get the order shown in Excel, `ORDER BY SERIAL_NUMBER, EVENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: @nfgl I can dense_rank may work I can get GROUP_ID column from dense_rank, however, I need to reset ranking after operation is 000 even still be a same serial_number parttition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested OLAP-functions, assuming `ORDER BY SERIAL_NUMBER, EVENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the order shown in Excel:

```
with cte as 
 (
    select ...
       case --IF(OR(A2<>A1,AND(B2<>"000",B1="000"))
         when (lag(OPERATION)
              over (order by SERIAL_NUMBER, EVENT_TIMESTAMP) = '000'
              and OPERATION <> '000')
           or lag(SERIAL_NUMBER,1,'')
              over (order by SERIAL_NUMBER, EVENT_TIMESTAMP) <> SERIAL_NUMBER
         then 1
         else 0
       end as flag -- start of new group
    from tab
 ) 
select ...
   sum(flag)
   over (order by SERIAL_NUMBER, EVENT_TIMESTAMP
         rows unbounded preceding) as GROUP_ID
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is counting the number of "breaks" in your data, where a "break" is defined as `000` or the value in the first column changing.

In SQL, you can do this as a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_serial_number = serial_number or operation <> '000'
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by event_timestamp rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as column_d
from (select t.*,
             lag(serial_number) over (order by event_timestamp) as prev_serial_number
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you very much I got your point. It's seem it's almost there. I need to try a bit to tune for exact result.